# Stack Overflow stopped working on my iOS devices several days ago

Tags: support, browser-support, ios

As of some time last week, I can no longer use Stack Overflow on my iPad. The 'comment', 'show more comments', voting, and 'edit tags' buttons do nothing, and possibly other things as well.

At one point I briefly saw a message about JavaScript being loaded from another untrusted site, but only once.

iOS 9.3.6, Safari.

Comment: What version of Safari? If it's tied to your iOS version, it's [probably not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support), and this probably won't be fixed anyway.

Comment: iOS 9 is relatively ancient. iOS 13 is the most recent, with iOS 14 about to be released this fall. Safari versions are indeed tied to iOS versions, with major Safari versions generally coming out at the same pace as major iOS versions.

Comment: iOS 9.3.6 was the last iOS version sent to the iPad 3, the iPad 2, and the iPad Mini. The iPad 2 is from 2011 and the other two are from 2012. It might be time to get a new iPad.

Comment: Im aware of the age of my device. IOS was last updated several years ago. That doesn't explain a change that took place last week.

Comment: @Zoe I don't know what the percentages mean in your link, or rather the link from your link, but if they're supposed to represent users they aren't even remotely credible.

Comment: The percentages aren't necessarily important. That's the browsers SE say they support - making yours unsupported. Picking on what browsers SE support is a whole other discussion, however.

Comment: There have been a number of changes to Stack Overflow over the last year to use more modern CSS (grids, flexbox, etc.). Maybe some more were rolled out in conjunction with the all-important reaction addition, and they happened to be the last straw for Safari 9. Who knows? You're already playing Russian roulette security-wise using an old OS version, Stack Overflow ceasing to work is the least of the potential problems.

Comment: There's a similar report on [older Firefox ESR](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14145) with the same Javascript issue.