# I cannot see comments on the Safari Browser

Tags: bug, comments, browser-support

I have asked following [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1561821/) on Super User.

I can see all the comments on the Opera Browser but I cannot see any of the comments on the Safari Browser. What might be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

But interestingly it only blocks comments on `Super User` and not on any other stack site.

- macOS Catalina Version 10.15.5 && Safari Version 13.1.1 (15609.2.9.1.2)

---

#### Please note that this only occurs for all the comments that occur on `Super User` site.

The reason was: I was using [1Blocker](https://1blocker.com/) on `Safari`. I enabled its option, which was `Block Comments: where they aren't the primary focus. (I have no idea it exists)`. I disabled it and it starts working fine.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398671/so-stopped-working-on-my-ios-devices-several-days-ago

Comment: Might be useful to identify your OS and your Browser versions (especially for Safari).

Comment: macOS Catalina Version `10.15.5` && Safari Version `13.1.1 (15609.2.9.1.2)`

Comment: Any extensions that might be messing with the page?

Comment: If this is about a question on Super User, would it not be better suited to the Super User Meta?

Comment: I'm also running macOS Catalina 10.15.5 and Safari 13.1 and it shows up just fine.

Comment: Should I delete the question and ask on `Super User Meta`? As extension I am only using only `1Blocker` and `AdGuard `on the Safari

Comment: 1: Yes, you should. 2: Try disabling them first.

Comment: Ah `1Blocker` had an option `Block Comments: where they aren't the primary focus.` (I have no idea it exists). I disabled it and it starts working fine. But interestingly it only blocks comments on super-user and not on any other stack site @GalaxyCat105

Comment: If it's _all_ sites, not just Super User or Stack Overflow, I think it might be better to put it on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Bug reports can be posted on any site.